# How can I import packages in Pyscript.net?

Tags: python, html, pyscript

So, I want to run Python in HTML. I found https://pyscript.net/ and it seems to work. "Easy code" with no import works fine. But as soon as I want to import for examlpe Kivy, normally I do it in my Terminal by: pip install kivy. How can I "pip install kivy" in Pyscript? So it works in the browser?

I saw something like that:

```
   <py-env>
        kivy
    </py-env>
```

(in HTML under ). But it doesnt work. I tried, I doesnt work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The current answer is correct. I recommend that you read some of the numerous examples out there so that you understand how to write Python code that interacts with the web browser. I wrote about 20 articles on PyScript.

Answer (score 2):

pyscript does not support the installing of packages but has a large and growing library of modules that can be called by defining them in the `<py-env>`,
e.g

```
  <py-env>
  - pandas
  </py-env>
```

Then importing the module as usual in the `<py-script>`,
e.g `import pandas`.